# MS Dynamics CRM. Managed solution to unmanaged

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, solution

I want to Import a plugin to managed solution, but I can't do that even under System Administrator security role. What I need to do? Is it possible to change managed solution to unmanaged?

Answer (score 2):

If the solution you are importing contains assemblies (plug-ins or workflow assembly DLLs) then the solution import will fail if you are not set up as a deployment administrator. The System Administrator security role alone may not be enough privilege.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit a managed solution, this is by design, I suggest looking into solution management for further details.

[Introduction to Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334576.aspx)

You can make a solution unmanaged though, but you will need a copy of the XML customisations, edit that XML and then import into a new environment.

[Change a Managed Solution to Unmanaged in MS CRM 2011](http://my-devils-workshop.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/change-managed-solution-to-unmanaged-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible by design. Even it won't work if you try to amend customization.xml. Because `XML` schema for managed and unmanaged solutions are different and you will get an error.

Comment: I tried it myself and got the error, it could be because of any other reason. If you are saying than I believe its worth trying again. However its a hack but I will have a go again :)

Comment: I did do it quite a while ago (1ish year), so maybe newer roll ups have removed that ability.